# How can i filter this dataframe for values != 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Guys i have this dataframe

```
+----------+--------------------+-----------+----------+---+------+----------+
|test|         content|         environment|         ID|dddd|dddd| date|
+----------+--------------------+-----------+----------+---+------+----------+
|         0|{ "$set" : { "sta...|test|        400146779|  u| Mongo| 123123123|
|         0|{ "$set" : { "sta...|test|       -307131663|  u|     0|         0|
|   charges|{ "$set" : { "sta...|test|                0|  u| mongo|1556816209|
|   charges|{ "$set" : { "sta...|test|         19920822|  u| mongo|1556816209|
+----------+--------------------+-----------+----------+---+------+----------+
```

How could i filter this dataframe and create a new one with only rows that don't have a 0 in its columns

so the only value on the new dataframe would be

```
charges|{ "$set" : { "sta...|test|         19920822|  u| mongo|1556816209
```

because it doesn't contain a 0.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean, the row should be filtered out if it has any int or long column with value 0? Have you already tried anything?

Comment: yeah, it should do

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: val successDF = dataFrame.filter($"ID" !== 0) 

i'm trying something like this but it only checks one column, iwould like to check every column for 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `filter` of `dataset`:

```
val dsWithoutZeros = ds.filter(r => r.toSeq.forall{
   //filter out row if any value in row is number and is equal 0
   case i: Number => i.longValue() != 0 
   case _ => true //if value is not number, just return neutral value for forall
})
```